# Determining MediaWiki version from the database only

Tags: php, sql, mediawiki

Ok, so. My MediaWiki migration from a server in the U.S. to a server in Germany backfired, horribly, and I ended up with ONLY the database. The ENTIRE mediawiki installation was irrevocably lost.

I do NOT remember what version of MediaWiki the site was running, although it was semi-modern (sometime after January 2012).

The PostgreSQL database has been successfully restored in the new server.

Is there any SQL I can query to give me the version information? I have tried upgrading from 1.19 but it gives me *all* sorts of "columns already exist" errors and generally fails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommends to simply upgrade to the latest version and not to worry about which version you had before.

MediaWiki *should* upgrade gracefully from any version (after 1.5) to the current. However, it is possible that this is not as smooth with PostGres as it is with MySQL, and it's also possible that some extensions don't do this well.

Please report any failures of the upgrade process to http://bugs.wikimedia.org.

**EDIT**: to answer the original question: the best way to find the MediaWiki version by looking at the database would be this query:

```
select max(ul_key) from updatelog where ul_key like 'updatelist-%';
```

**YMMV**, however. This is not an official or recommended version check. It looks at a table used for logging database updates, and gives you the latest version found in entries that start with "updatelist". These entries may go away, or change appreance. Also, I'm not sure PG supports the LIKE syntax I gave.

The best way to check your MediaWiki version is to look at **Special:Version** or, if the wiki isn't running, check **$wgVersion** in includes/DefaultSettings.php.

Comment: You're right, with one caveat: It doesn't handle installing over future versions well at all! I tried installing 1.19.5 but it crashed and burned. But upgrading to 1.21.2 did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: +1 because while you didn't answer the asked question, you did address the real issue, which, when I was in a similar position, was more important.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith It looks like your question has been answered. You should probably mark it as such now.

Comment: Wow! I just realized that two years after his/her original answer, @brightbyte actually came back and edited it in! Accepted + Amazed!

Comment: I wonder why the answer got 6 up votes and the question only 1, especially when it's been viewed > 1,000x...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot get the correct version number out of the database. If you have access to backups of the php files, it is much easier and more reliable.

Depending on the Mediawiki version, you can find the version definition in either `includes/DefaultSettings.php` or in `includes/Defines.php`.

- `includes/Defines.php` contains the definition of the `MW_VERSION` constant since version 1.31.
  For example:
  `define( 'MW_VERSION', '1.35.8' );`
- `includes/DefaultSettings.php` contains the `$wgVersion` variable definition for older versions, up to around version 1.30.
  For example:
  `$wgVersion = '1.19.24';` or
  `$wgVersion = '1.29.3';`

Or you can use a one-liner like this to find it:

```bash
grep -E 'wgVersion|MW_VERSION' /var/lib/mediawiki/includes/{DefaultSettings,Defines}.php
```

I have 2 Mediawiki installs, using PostgreSQL. One on an old Debian 8 Jessie, and one on a Debian recently upgraded to v. 10 Buster.

In both cases querying just the database doesn't work or gives wrong results.

On the old Debian 8 with Mediawiki version 1.19, this SQL query gives a much older version:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d wikidb -t -c "SELECT type, mw_version, sql_date, cdate FROM mediawiki.mediawiki_version"
 Update | 1.15.4     | $LastChangedDate: 2009-12-16 04:24:12 +1100 (Wed, 16 Dec 2009) $ | 2010-06-17 14:31:18.745713+02
```

And this has no such key in the table, so it returns nothing:

```
$ psql -U postgres -t -d wikidb -c "SELECT max(ul_key) FROM updatelog WHERE ul_key LIKE 'updatelist-%';"
```

On the Debian 10 machine with version 1.31:

This gives the same wrong old version as on the other machine:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d wikidb -t -c "SELECT type, mw_version, sql_date, cdate FROM mediawiki.mediawiki_version"
 Creation | 1.15.5-2squeeze5 | $LastChangedDate: 2009-03-20 12:15:41 +1100 (Fri, 20 Mar 2009) $ | 2013-05-11 11:57:22.946184+02
```

And the query suggested in [brightbyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19078222/111036), which *should* give the right result, doesn't. It gives the version 1.27, which was right before the upgrade:

```
$ psql -U postgres -t -d wikidb -c "SELECT max(ul_key) FROM updatelog WHERE ul_key LIKE 'updatelist-%';"
 updatelist-1.27.4-15461109030
```

So, **don't use the database to find the correct version**.

Also note that after an upgrade, you probably need to run `update.php` in the `maintenance` directory to update the database schema. And to be able to do that, you need a working "LocalSettings.php" configuration, and for PostgreSQL, also the correct php pgsql library and Apache module.